# How can I set the TTY font size manually in Lubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tty, lubuntu

I'm configuring some minimal Lubuntu installs, which will run within VMs. They do not have window managers, and I do not intend to install any. I would like to increase the TTY font size so that 4 of these VMs can be tiled on a single display, and yet still be usable, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I assume there's just a conf file somewhere (/etc/....?) where this can be set. If someone could point me at that, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does Ubuntu still use `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`?

Comment: @jasonwryan Apparently not, or at least, my minimal install of lubuntu doesn't recognise that as a valid command, or even something in apt.

Comment: @Tim That is in fact a perfect duplicate, though I spent nearly 20 minutes searching before posting the question, and didn't see that one. Probably because I assumed this was system dependent. Maybe we should add a tag to the other question?

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of using Google to query any Stack site because Stack search is... well lacking apparently.

Answer (score 2):

So, after some tinkering, it seems this is done in two steps.

You can edit the font and font size manually in

```
/etc/default/console-setup
```

On my system, doing this alone doesn't seem to change the console size on boot, but running

```
# setupcon
```

causes the TTY to adopt the correct settings.